# Using regex to include or exclude everything between commas (python)

Tags: python, regex

I need to know how to exclude words that are in between commas using regex, i.e., "Lobasso, Jr., Sion" (I don't want the *Jr.*), so I have two ideas to use regex to include only words that are in between the two commas "ha,hello,bla" (*hello*) or to exclude the words that are between the commas, "he,blabla,lado" (*helado*).

Comment: Is it necessary to use regex for this, or was that just your best idea about how to solve the problem? Will you be satisfied by an answer that does not use regex?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes people will add additional designations to their name. There also may be 0 or more whitespaces that appear before/after a comma. To cover those cases (and avoid having to import `re`) consider using `split()` followed by `strip()`

```
strings = [
    "Lobasso, Jr., Sion",
    "Lobasso, Jr., B.Sc., Sion",
    "Lobasso   ,    Jr.   ,    B.Sc.   ,    Sion",
    "Lobasso,Sion"
]

for string in strings:
    result = string.split(",")
    print(result[0].strip(),  result[-1].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Exclude: `result = re.sub(r',([^,]*),', '', string)`

```
>>> print(re.sub(r',[^,]*,', '', "Lobasso, Jr., Sion"))
Lobasso Sion
>>> print(re.sub(r',[^,]*,', '', "he,blabla,lado"))
helado
```

Include: `result = ''.join(re.findall(r',([^,]*),', string))`

```
>>> print(''.join(re.findall(r',([^,]*),', "ha,hello,bla")))
hello
```

in both cases, the regex is of the pattern

```
r',([^,]*),'
   (     )      a capture group, containing   (these are only necessary in Include)
        *       zero or more occurrences of
    [^,]        any character other than ','
  ,       ,     with a ',' on both sides
```

If a regex contains exactly one capture group then `re.findall()` will return on whatever is found *in that capture group* instead of what's in *the entire matching string*, so in this case both expressions will act on whatever was matched by `[^,]*` - the thing between the commas.

- to include, we find all the occurrences of text surrounded by commas, take them out, and then use `''.join()` to stitch them back together without anything in between
- to exclude, we replace all occurrences of text surrounded by commas, and the surrounding commas, with the empty string

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude everything between commas like this:

```
print(re.sub(',.*,', '', "Lobasso, Jr., Sion"))
print(re.sub(',.*,', '', "he,blabla,lado"))
```

Output:

```
Lobasso Sion
helado
```